# Swift ambiguous reference to member '-' in array joining

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm running into some issues creating an array out of other arrays and slices of other arrays. All arrays referenced here are `internal static let [UInt16]` declared earlier. They are all contained in the same struct.

```
internal static let bigarray = [UInt16]([0, array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, [UInt16](array6.prefix(upTo: array6.count-8))].joined())
```

If the stuff involving `array6` is removed, everything is hunky-dory. But as soon as I add the `array6` slice, Swift complains that the - (minus) operator is ambiguous. How is this possible? Since `array6.count` and 8 are both `Ints`, shouldn't it just do simple integer subtraction and pass that as the upTo argument for prefix?

Comment: give space before and after - (minus) and check once

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: It is ambiguous because the array can contain AnyObject meaning every object in the array could be of a different type. Therefore the compiler can't know in advance whether any two objects in the array can be joined.

Comment: But I'm specifically casting the prefix as the correct type of array! How can I fix the problem I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The real problem is that
the first element `0` in the "array of arrays"

```
[0, array1, array2, ... ]
```

is not an array, but a number. Changing that to `[0]` should solve the problem. Note that the expression can be simplified slightly to

```
let bigarray = [[0], array1, array2, array3, array4, array5, Array(array6.dropLast(8))].joined()
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much. I feel silly not catching that. Problem solved!

Comment: @AJS: No problem. I have added a simpler expression.